# How do i connect my containerised project to kafka running on localhost?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've been trying to connect my containerised spring-boot project with a of kafka and zookeeper running on my localhost but i seem to be getting an error when  i run the docker images.

[image]

does anyone know what could be causing this  error and if so , what the best way to go about fixing it?

i alreadyhave ports 9092 and 2021 exposed

**edit:**
i was asked to post the text:

```
2020-04-15 06:55:34,872 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=message] Connection with /172.17.59.17 disconnected
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:216)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:531)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:262)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:249)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:326)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1251)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:993)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:901)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-15 06:55:34,874 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleDisconnections - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=message] Node -1 disconnected.
```

Comment: Why is there a `/` showing up before IP?

Comment: kafka seems to add the  /  at the beginning of the IP for some reason. but as far as i am aware it doesn't seem to affect the connection and is ignored

Comment: Please can you post the actual text, not a screenshot. As an image it makes it harder for people to read, and also cannot be searched by people in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Kafka broker with correct `advertised.listeners`. At the moment your Spring client is connecting to the broker for the initial connection, but then receives an internal IP/host from Kafka for subsequent connections, which then fail.

[Here's an example of Docker and Zookeeper running in Docker](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-to-database/docker-compose.yml#L1-L44) with listeners configured for external connections.

You can read more here: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Can we please start closing these questions as duplicates? I editted my answer there to be a wiki so I don't get rep. And your blog is linked there and it offers solutions for all popular Kafka container images...